# Resizeable CSS & HTML table with fixed header

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble creating a table that fits my needs with CSS and HTML.

My requirements are :

1. The table has a fixed width and height.
2. The table has a vertical scrollbar (if it gets too long).
3. The header is fixed, meaning that if I scroll down it stays in place.
4. The columns are horizontally resizeable.
5. overflow:hidden; on the cells so they don't take up many lines.

It has proven more challenging that I thought, I found solutions that satisfy some of the requirements but I could not satisfy all of them with any combination.

Can you guide me on how it can be done? I am willing to use a framework if there is no other choice.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: do you mean like this one ?? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NRoqgm

Comment: tried it already, doesn't work

Comment: it uses some pre-processor or something, i dont have it

Comment: It uses LESS, but you can switch it to show compiled CSS

Comment: Works but it is not resizeable